# Visual Studio versions and Composite WPF (Prism)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, prism

The documentation for Prism 2.1 says that VS 2008 is required.

In order to use Prism 4 you must upgrade to VS 2010.

But is it possible to continue to develop using Prism 2.1 if you upgrade to VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is you just need to target .Net 3.5.